# Mysql Foreign Key Relation Select Statement

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

**Edge   and  Edgematerials**

**Edge** consist of

```
Edge_ID type location
```

**Edgematerrials** consist of

```
EdgeMaterial_ID, Edge_ID,name, quality, lat, lon,
```

So it can be seen that `Edge_ID` is the foreign key in `EdgeMaterial` table.

Now, how may i get a name `carbon` from the **EdgeMaterial** table, where the "type" which is found in the Edge table is `poli` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with an [**`INNER JOIN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) query as follow

```
SELECT a.name
FROM Edgematerrials a 
INNER JOIN Edge b
ON a.Edge_ID = b.Edge_ID
WHERE b.type LIKE 'poli'
```